# WebdriverJS Expect Arrays to be equal ignoring order

Tags: arrays, selenium-webdriver, assert

As we have method in jasmine to match array without the order (arrayContaining), similar thing i'm looking in webdriver.

```
var array1 = [a,b];
var array2 = [b,a];

expect(array1).to.containArray(array2);  // something like this ignoring order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be useful for someone,  here is the solution for it.

```
   expect(array1).to.have.members(array2);
```